# How to implement three mutually exclusive Forms

Tags: html, forms, user-interface, user-experience

How would you handle having three forms in one page but only allowing the user to use one for input and therefore making the others inactive/disabled, in the most user friendly way.

Say for example having the user choose of one of the following forms:

- URL
- file
- text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a set of tabs. Only reveal the relevant form when the corresponding tab is active.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs

Give each form it's own submit button, enforces only one option can be submitted.